# RSS feed and program updates in MFC app

Tags: c++, mfc, rss, requirements

My boss wants me to write a simple RSS feed for an C++ MFC app that will pull and display information from the company's website. It also must be able to grab program updates from the website, tell the user that there are updates and then install the updates. Are there any tutorials that follow these guide lines? How would stackoverflow.com implement these requirements? Libraries, tutorials or guidance would all be great!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RSS is not more than XML ([Ref](http://cyber.law.harvard.edu/rss/rss.html)). Under Windows/MFC you can use MSXML directly or use [this](http://www.codeguru.com/cpp/data/data-misc/xml/article.php/c4575) MSXML wraper class, [tinyxml](http://www.grinninglizard.com/tinyxml/), or other any other XML library to handle XML.

**Update**:
To download RSS you can use [CHttpFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0tw8chfe(VS.80).aspx).

Comment: Thanks for the post. What about grabbing program updates and installing them? any ideas?

Comment: Your update helps with downloading the xml data, but if I wanted to download a .msi or .exe patch and execute it how could i do that?

Comment: Using RSS you know the latest version. If a new version exists, go download it using CHttpFile also.